# Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10 install fails on OMEN by HP 17-cb0013nm (RTX 2080)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, system-installation, kernel, hp

I bought a very recent laptop https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/omen-by-hp-17-cb0000-laptop-pc/26122176/document/c06411586 .

It has Nvidia RTX 2080 video card, and a WiFi adapter that requires kernel v5.1 at least, so it is reasonable I cannot install Ubuntu 18.04.3 which has v5.0 kernel version.

But I cannot even install Ubuntu 19.10 which comes with Nvidia drivers on the ISO (if I understood correctly), and has v5.3 kernel. I tried several options in the GRUB settings that are suggested here on AskUbuntu but none managed to solve the problem.

How can I report this to the Ubuntu team, so it gets fixed in 18.04.4 or at least in 20.04? (notice I cannot use the install form from Ubuntu, because I cannot install it at all)

Comment: Make a bug report at Launchpad.net https://launchpad.net/+search?field.text=19.10 after you have prepared an explanation of the error messages you received when you chose each of the available options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: The problem is I send the form from my Ubuntu, because I cannot install it at all!!!

Comment: Did you verify ISO download? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and validate install media? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck   Those steps may not be your problem, but I'd at least validate install media.

Comment: These are correct, many others have same problem.

Comment: Can you run the 'try ubuntu' (ie. 'live' mode), `ubuntu-bug` can be run from there.

Comment: Not even try ubuntu is working @guiverc

Comment: I'd suggest using "*Filing bugs manually at Launchpad.net*" from link (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) provided earlier by K7AAY   *In your place I'd try the Ubuntu 18.04.4 daily (or 20.04) as I know it has many fixes that aren't in 18.04.3, but no idea about your issues though*

Comment: 19.10 uses 5.3 kernel @heynnema

Comment: Exactly what error messages, or symptoms, do you see when you try to boot a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: @heynnema I opened this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188788/cannot-install-ubuntu-20-04-on-omen-by-hp-17-cb0013nm I think the same behavior is on 19.10. 18.04 managed to install with some flags, but crashed after 1 min of being on.

Comment: @croraf see my comments at your other question. Note: It may be closed because it refers to the development version of Ubuntu. But there's more data in the form of screenshots there. Possible BIOS and HDD problems. Is your primary disk HDD or SSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the great comments above, the next actions to do are the following:

- try daily builds of 19.10 and 20.04 (I won't try 18.04 daily because it still has too old kernel version)
- if the problem persists I'll fill bug manually as described in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs, section "Filing bugs manually at Launchpad.net" and try some other distribution

EDIT: I'm currently able to work on the laptop (with some issues though, like microphone not working etc.) Check my (workaround) solution here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1852636

Answer (score 0):

on a similar laptop for installation from USB had to grab.cfg write acpi=off in linux line before root=...

Comment: I kinda resolved the issue. Check: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1852636

Comment: Can you describe with more explanation your answer?

Answer (score 0):

No solution here but I have the same issue with the OMEN 17-cb0221ng. I have the RXT 2070. I installed a 2nd solid state drive to install Ubuntu. I made a boot USB using the latest version of Rufus as the tutorial suggests.

- 18.04 hangs during driver unpacking with graphical wingdings at the bottom 25% of the screen. I assume it's an issue with the default Nvidia drivers Ubuntu is trying to install but I'm not savvy enough to forbid the default drivers and install the Nvidia suggested drivers...
- 19.10 with save mode drivers provides a list of errors. So many. I'm not sure where the install login file is if one is even saved at that early stage.
- 20.04 - Black screens with ACPI error.

  ```
  ucsi_ccg 0-0008: failed to reset PPMI
  ```

  [image: 20.04 - Black screen with ACPI error]

So, again, no solutions here.

Comment: 20.04 is still in beta test, not a final build is done (would be released in april 2020 as Ubuntu version are composed as *yy* . *mm*

Comment: I just made a USB boot drive using Rufus with 20.04 daily. Tried installing it with the save graphics installer and the normal installer. Both gave me the purple Ubuntu logo screen straight away which was new, but both failed after a bunch of command prompt entries. Something about evga drivers failing. The screen was full of failed lines and then the final line was existing some emergency mode... I know bad details, but I'm pretty confident that it's because my laptop is just too new and the necessary drivers aren't available in the 20.04 install package yet. So, I'll just wait, I guess !!

Comment: see this link : https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle

Comment: Thanks, Damadam. That's a helpful link. Looks like 16.04 won't cover the new hardware, but 18.04 will cover new hardware; eventually... Thanks for cleaning up my post. I wasn't sure what information would be helpful so I just included it all. If more information is necessary, I'm happy to run a new daily version and post the result somewhere if that's helpful. Cheers

Comment: @McPhil check how I solved it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1852636

Comment: @croraf - I went through launchpad but it didn't work for me. I'll try it again over the weekend as I'm out of time for the moment. Is there any additional minutia that would be helpful? I'd really love to get this working...

Comment: Just try what described in last couple of comments there. Or try asking on Ubuntu IRC channel.

Answer (score 0):

I could make dual boot environment of Ubuntu18.04 and Windows10 on OMEN HP 17-cb0004TX.  
1. Secure boot -> false, legacy boot -> true in BIOS
2. Boot from USB and press “e” to edit option (add ACPI=off)
3. Install Ubuntu and find error message about “grub-Eli-amd64-signed”.
4. Connect network and launch “software & updates” and check “community-maintained free and...”
5. $sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
6. $sudo apt install -y boot-repair
7. Launch boot-repair and click “Recommended repair”, and find error message “An error occurred during the repair.” But, its OK. 
8. Reboot and maybe it will boot Windows10 without seeing Grub.
9. Launch command prompt as administrator and type “bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path ¥EFI¥Ubuntu¥shimx64.efi” 
10. Reboot 
11. You can see grub selector. 
12. Push “e” and add “ACPI=off” and push F10. 
Enjoy! Dual boot environment!!